# Keras TypeError: incompatible function arguments (dlib model)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, face-recognition, dlib

I am generating some face images using `Conv2DTranspose` followed by a 1x1 `Conv2D`. I need to have a face detection Keras custom layer that later will be used to generate facial landmarks for my loss function.

I used `dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1` to detect faces but the problem is it only accepts list or arrays and not tensors. Plus in graph definition stage the tensors have not yet been fed with any values. So, it keeps throwing me this error:

```
TypeError: __call__(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1, imgs: list, upsample_num_times: int=0, batch_size: int=128) -> std::vector<std::vector<dlib::mmod_rect,std::allocator<dlib::mmod_rect> >,std::allocator<std::vector<dlib::mmod_rect,std::allocator<dlib::mmod_rect> > > >
    2. (self: dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1, img: array, upsample_num_times: int=0) -> std::vector<dlib::mmod_rect,std::allocator<dlib::mmod_rect> >

Invoked with: <dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1 object at 0x0000013474884D50>, <tf.Tensor 'conv2d/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 160, 160, 3) dtype=float32>, 1

Did you forget to `#include <pybind11/stl.h>`? Or <pybind11/complex.h>,
<pybind11/functional.h>, <pybind11/chrono.h>, etc. Some automatic
conversions are optional and require extra headers to be included
when compiling your pybind11 module.
```

Here's how I defined my landmarks detector layer:

```
class landmarks_layer(Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_outputs):
    super(landmarks_layer, self).__init__()
    self.num_outputs = num_outputs
  def call(self, input_):
    landmarks = find_landmarks68(input_)
    return landmarks
```

and here's my function to detect landmarks:

```
def find_landmarks68(img):
    cnn_face_detector =   
    dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1('mmod_human_face_detector.dat')
    dets = cnn_face_detector(img, 1)
    rects = dlib.rectangles()
    rects.extend([d.rect for d in dets])
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat") 
    shape = predictor(img, rects[0])
    (img_y,img_x,img_z) = img.shape
    landmarks = []
    for i in shape.parts():
        landmarks.append([i.y, i.x])    
    return landmarks
```

I expected that the layer would return a (None, 68, 2) tensor in graph definition stage but it executes the code and when it faces a tensor with no value, it throws me the error. So, I am stuck in the face detection stage right now and it doesn't proceed to landmarks detection. I thought I should've used `tf.cond` for checking on whether the batch number is None or not and if it is I don't know it just return a (None, 68, 2) tensor but if it is not, then it should've performed the landmarks detection in graph execution stage but it runs the code even graph definition stage.